# Rounded Rectangle Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have seen many Q's on this subject but none are exactly what I am trying to do. I have a view inside of a view and it's frame is a CGRectangle. I would like said rectangle to have rounded edges to look like a rounded rectangle button. If I could have some code examples on how to implement that it would be nice. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first need to import QuartzCore framework into your project. I hope you know how to do that. Than you can use the following code:

```
CALayer *l = [yourView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
// You can even add a border
[l setBorderWidth:1.0];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

Hope it helps! ;)

Comment: That was easy and it looks great. I have been trying to do that for weeks, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and add `QuartzCore` to the Existing Frameworks in order to gain access to the `cornerRadius:` method.

Then to set the corner radius you would use something like the following depending upon your implementation of the view

```
UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,200)];
CALayer *theViewLayer = [theView layer];
[theViewLayer setCorderRadius:5.0];

//Other Methods you can use
[theViewLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.3] CGColor]];
[theViewLayer setBorderWidth:2.0];
[theViewLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
```

Comment: Thank you. I used singingAtom's code but it was very similar. I appreciate the quick and thorough answers from both of you.